# PHP preg_replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, preg-replace

I had working preg_replace in PHP, but I had to move it to JavaScript code and it doesn't work there. I've searched here in topics, but haven't found working solution for me...
My PHP looked like:

```
preg_replace('/^\d+_/', '', $docTypes);
```

And now, my JS looks like, important thing, `var documentTypes` is `object`:

```
   var documentTypesObj = {};
   var counter = 0;
   {foreach $documentTypes as $key =>$value}
   documentTypesObj[counter + '_' + {$key}] = {$value};
   counter++;
   {/foreach}

    var documentTypes = documentTypesObj;

    documentTypes = documentTypes.map(d => { return d.replace(/^\d+_/g, "")});

    console.log(documentTypes);
```

Inside `var documentTypes` are values with prefix, which I have to remove. Values are for example:

```
0_xxxx
1_xxxx
2_xxxx
```

Thank you for advices!

Comment: You doubled a `/` at the end, it must be `/^\d+_/g`.

Comment: ^^^ and `documentTypes = documentTypes.replace(/^\d+_/, '');` you've to assign it back to variable to update it's value and no need of `g` flag.

Comment: @Tushar Code edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an array:

```
var docs = ["0_xxx", "1_yyy", "2_zzzz"];
docs = docs.map(d => { return d.replace(/^\d+_/g, "")});
```

Comment: actually it's object, when I use your solution, console.log says, that docs.map is not a function..:( but it told me that also when I tried to use `forEach()` and other functions...

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    documentTypes = '0_xxxx';
    documentTypes = documentTypes.replace(/^\d+_/, '');
    document.write(documentTypes);
</script>
```

Comment: No explanation? Code only answers are not helpful for future readers. Please [edit] the answer and add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

not sure on your input string, problem might be becouse you have line feed or carry return in string. If so, the solution you are looking for might be this:

```
var documentTypes = '0_xxxx\n\
1_xxxx\n\
2_xxxx';

documentTypes = documentTypes.replace(/(^\d+_|[\r\n]+\d+_)/gm,'');
```